# How to loop through JSON data in SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift3, swifty-json

I have a JSON data with structure and I don't know how to use for-loop with SwiftyJSON to get each sections entries of "path" and "updated" value. Anyone can help? Thanks.

```
var jsonData = "{
      "css":[
         {
            "path": "style.css",
            "updated": "12432"
         },
         {
            "path": "base.css",
            "updated": "34627"
         },

      ],
      "html":[
         {
            "path": "home.htm",
            "updated": "3223"
         },
         {
            "path": "about",
            "updated": "3987"
         }
      ]
    }
"
```

**I tried to code part of for-loop**

```
let json = JSON(jsonData)

for ( ) in json {
   let filepath = 
   let updated = 

   // do searching another json to found file exists and updates
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's on the README, under the section named "loop": https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON#loop

```
// If json is .Dictionary
for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
   //Do something you want
}

// If json is .Array
// The `index` is 0..<json.count's string value
for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
    //Do something you want
}
```

Applied to your specific JSON structure:

```
    let jsonData = """
    {
      "css": [
        {
          "path": "style.css",
          "updated": "12432"
        },
        {
          "path": "base.css",
          "updated": "34627"
        }
      ],
      "html": [
        {
          "path": "home.htm",
          "updated": "3223"
        },
        {
          "path": "about",
          "updated": "3987"
        }
      ]
    }
    """.data(using: .utf8)!

    let json = JSON(data: jsonData)

    for (_, subJson):(String, JSON) in json {

        for (_, subJson):(String, JSON) in subJson {
            let filepath = subJson["path"].stringValue
            let updated  = subJson["updated"].stringValue

            print(filepath + " ~ " + updated)
        }
    }
```

---

Using Swift 4 Codable:

```
struct FileInfo: Decodable {
    let path, updated: String
}

let dec = try! JSONDecoder().decode([String:[FileInfo]].self,from: jsonData)
print(dec)
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your JSON structure, use this :

```
for (index,subJson):(String, JSON) in json {
    print(index) // this prints "css" , "html"
    for (key,subJson):(String, JSON) in subJson {
        let filepath = subJson["path"]
        let updated  = subJson["updated"]
    }
}
```